# trigger AJAX action when click on button inside dropdown without closing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

As you probably know, any action inside twitter's bootstrap leads to the closing of the dropdown except when using :

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(event){
         event.stopPropagation();
      })
```

Unfortunately, `event.stopPropagation()` stops the ajax query as well.
what I want to achieve is something like when you get a friend request on FB and you accept/decline inside the dropdown without it being closed. 
Can you help me ?

Comment: Make the AJAX call explicitly after to stop the event.

Comment: Hi ! Something like e.preventDefault() for ajax submit! thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the ajax call after the `event.stopPropagation` call.

In this case, the click should be on `$('.dropdown-menu > li > a')` element. See example below.

```js
/**** Ignore this command - just used to mock up an ajax response **/
$.mockjax({
  url: '/likethis',
  responseTime: 1000,
  responseText: {
    status: 'success',
    fbStatus: 'liked'
  }
});

$('.dropdown-menu > li > a').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  
    $.ajax({ url: '/likethis',
              success: function() {
                 $('#likelink').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Liked!');
              }
           });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mockjax/1.5.3/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Like This <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#" id="likelink">Like</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```